# RegistryNotifyCallback equivalent for Windows Phone

Tags: c++, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-mobile-6.5

In Windows Mobile I could use RegistryNotifyCallback and get notified when certain data changed.

Is there any equivalent to this function in Windows Phone 8?

Since RegistryNotifyCallback was used in C++ (unmanaged code) and WP uses .Net (managed code), is there any way to directly import and use the necessary C++ DLLs?

The functionality I'm looking for here is to get notified if a Contact from my People Hub changes any of its data, outside my application. I've asked this question before and the short answer was "the is no way of doing this", but I'm still hoping there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've asked this question before and the short answer was "the is no way of doing this",

Why are you asking again then? It's still the same answer. And we don't have any intentions, whatsoever, to allow 3rd party developers to access data from limited contact stores.

Comment: I was asking again because in essence it's a different question. I'm curios to see if I can import this function and use it in Windows Phone. Thank you for the answer! I'm working on a cloud sync application, and one of the features would be syncing contacts. Manually checking every X seconds if modifications occurred in the contact list was not desirable, that's why I was hoping for an automation.